# Define a pair/point as a pair/point along a path length METAPOST

Tags: metapost, epstopdf

Is it possible to define a pair as a point along a specified length of a path?

so for example

```
beginfig
u=2cm;
path x;
x=(0,0)..u*dir(225);
%v= a point along a fraction of the length of x in a specific direction 
endfig
```

Answer (score 8):

The *along* operator defined in the Metafun format of MetaPost specifies a point as fraction of a path:

```
beginfig(1);
  u=2cm;
  path x; x=(0,0)..u*dir(225); draw x;
  pair v; v = point .3 along x;
  dotlabel.lrt(btex v etex, v);
endfig;
end.
```

To be compiled with the `mem` flag: `mpost --mem=metafun yourfile.mp`. Result:

[image]

As an alternative you may load the `mp-tool.mpii` package at the beginning of your program (but you won't benefit of the full capacities of Metafun then, such as transparency):

```
input mp-tool.mpii;
```

Or if you want to stick to the `plain` format, you may define the `along` operator yourself. It is defined as such in the [Metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf), p. 61:

```
primarydef pct along pat = 
  (arctime (pct * (arclength pat)) of pat) of pat
enddef;
```

In the Metafun format (cf. manual, idem p. 61) is also the *on* operator defined, which specifies the position of a point with a dimension:

```
primarydef len on pat =
  (arctime len of pat) of pat 
enddef;
```

Applied to our program, it would be used like that, for the same result:

```
beginfig(1);
  u=2cm;
  path x; x=(0,0)..u*dir(225); draw x;
  pair v; v = point .6cm on x;
  dotlabel.lrt(btex v etex, v);
endfig;
end.
```